# why sfml get error when include it after include windows.h?

Tags: c++, include, sfml

I been using SFML for a while, I create a window by follow the instruction, it work perfect and fine.

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However when I include the windows.h right before include the SFML/Graphics.hpp part like this.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
```

This shows several errors.

But when I include the windows.h after the SFML/Graphics.hpp like this.

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <windows.h>
```

It work fine and no ERRO, I recheck and recognize this bug only pop with the Graphics.hpp part, if I include other like Window.hpp, System.hpp it work fine too.

Why is this?

Comment: Please include the 1st few (5 ish) errors in the question. Likely explanation is `#define`s clashes.

Comment: `<windows.h>` is well known to define various macros which mess with other header files. It's unfortunate but they can't change it now. Putting `#define NOMINMAX` before `#include <windows.h>` can help.

Comment: nah, at first it seem to be good, but when I open include file of sfml like Vector2.inl, Rect.inl on current project, that file pop up error everwhere, and my project slowly pop up error of all sfml include file . Example Vector2.inl definition can't find Declaration on Vector2.hpp file, like it don't recognize it own file.

Comment: So, the solution for this is: ALWAY INCLUDE WINDOWS.H AFTER INCLUDE SFML FILE.